# i run code from thread it doesnt work, i run core from onclick event and it works

Tags: .net, multithreading, delegates, vb.net-2010

I have the following code:

```
Private Delegate Sub delegate_updateList1(ByVal lista)

Public Sub actualiza_listbox1(ByVal lista)
        If ListBox1.InvokeRequired Then

            ListBox1.Invoke(New delegate_updateList1(AddressOf actualiza_listbox1), New Object() {lista})
        Else
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            For Each item As String In lista
                ListBox1.Items.Add(item)

                Me.Text = item
            Next

        End If
       ListBox1.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

        Dim thread_filtra As New Thread(Sub() buscador.filtra(TextBox1.Text))

        If thread_filtra.IsAlive Then
            thread_filtra.Abort()
        End If

        thread_filtra.Start()
    End Sub
```

buscador.filtra is a function that does some things and calls  main.actualiza_listbox1(filtrados) before finishing

If i run it manually (for example on an onclick event) as :

buscador.filtra(TextBox1.Text)

All is ok, and everything is processed and displayed correctly, but if i create the thread as displayed on texbox1_textchanged , all seems ok internally (step by step seems allright, all subs end correctly and all variables have correct data) but nothing gets displayed on listbox1

Does anyone knows what could i be doing wrong? I suppose that is something with the way the thread is created or the delegate used, but i couldn't be able to find the error.

Searched msdn documentation , stack overflown posts and some other sites, and the code seems to be correct, but im not able to find the fault.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i 've making tests and i definitely think the problem is in the way the delegate is used, but im not able to find the errors, the delegate is created inside form1 , and the thread calls  main.actualiza_listbox1(filtrados), but when called it never gets "invoked" it allways execute the other path and that is i think the error, but i cant find the correct way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub FilterBy_Change("load")

    Dim sql As String
    "loadatomautocorrctionanswerresultsprewiev"
    'This will match any entry in the list that begins with what the user 
    'has typed in the FilterBy control
    sql = "SELECT ColorID, ColorName FROM Colors WHERE ColorName Like '" & Me.FilterBy.Text & "*' ORDER BY ColorName"
    
    'If you want to match any part of the string then add wildcard (*) before
    'the FilterBy.Text, too:
    'sql = "SELECT ColorID, ColorName FROM Colors WHERE ColorName Like '*" & Me.FilterBy.Text & "*' ORDER BY ColorName"
    
    Me.ColorID.RowSource = sql
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What's this got to do with the question?